# multiple Orderby and Sort

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have 2 classes:

```
 Employee
 EmployeeDetails
```

I would like to have a list with first ordering of Employee then sort it, then EmployeeDetails orderby and then sort it.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
var result = _db.Employee
              .OrderBy( e => e.EmpName )
              .Sort('DepartmentId') // using the diff property
              .ThenBy( ed => ed.EmpAddress )
              .Sort('PostCode'); // using the diff property
```

I need to first order by `EmpName` from Employee then Sort it after from those resultset I want to orderby EmpAddress and Sort it and then return the resultset.

Is this even possible?  Can it be done without using Lambdas?  Are the other approaches?

Comment: Do you want the same data twice, with two different sorts, or just once sorting on `EmpName` and then `EmpAddress` as a tiebreaker?

Comment: "ordering by" is a synonym for "sorting". What do you mean by "have a list with first ordering of Employee then sort it" then?..

Answer (score 7):

Is the following code what you're looking for?

```
var result = _db.Employee
                .OrderBy(e => e.EmpName)
                .ThenBy(e => e.DeptartmentId)
                .ThenBy(e => e.EmpAddresss)
                .ThenBy(e => e.PostCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for:

```
var result = _db.Employee
              .OrderBy( e => e.EmpName )  //OrderBy and SortBy empname  Ascending
              .ThenBy( ed => ed.EmpAddress ); //orderby address ascending
```

Comment: but why can't i use OrderBy().OrderBy() twice, rather then using ThenBy() or sort()

Comment: @patel.milanb, No the second `OrderBy()` needs to by `ThenBy()` it will be like `ORDER BY empname, address` in sql, but if you did two consecutive `OrderBy`s then you first order by the empname then re order the list with address, therefore the last order by will be applied and the first one will be omitted.

Comment: because the second OrderBy() will re-sort the results of the first sort by the second criterion alone.  It will 'forget' that any previous sort had been performed.

Answer (score 1):

If your `Employee` class has an `EmployeeDetails` property with the `EmpAddress`, you could do this:

```
var result = _db.Employee
          .OrderBy( e => e.EmpName )
          .ThenBy( e => e.EmployeeDetails.EmpAddress );
```